# Chaining functions and keep a variable in the chain if needed

Tags: javascript, prototype, chaining

I have some code like this:

```
function Foo( arr, prop ) {
  this.arr = arr;
  this.isOn = prop;
}

function newFoo( arr, prop ) {
  return new Foo( arr, prop );
}

Foo.prototype = {

  a: function() {
    var result = [];
    // do something and push to result
    if ( this.prop ) // do something different with result
    return newFoo( result );
  },

  // This is the method that determines if prop = true in the chain
  b: function() {
    result = [];
    // do something and push to result
    // this time 'prop' must be 'true'
    return newFoo( result, true )
  }

};
```

I want to keep passing `true` if the previous element in the chain has `prop`. Obvisouly the above approach doesn't work as you can see here:

```
var nf = newFoo;
console.log( nf( [1,2,3] ).b().isOn ); //=> true
console.log( nf( [1,2,3] ).b().a().isOn ); //=> undefined
```

I know I could just return `newFoo( result, this.prop )` all the time on every method but I was curious to see if there are any other solutions to this problem. As methods grow in number it'll be hard to keep track of this property over time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As methods grow in number it'll be hard to keep track of this property over time.

You could just create an extra method with the functionality of `newFoo` that automatically keeps track of the properties you are not going to overwrite:

```
function Foo( arr, prop ) {
  this.arr = arr;
  this.isOn = prop;
}

Foo.prototype = {

  clone: function newFoo( arr, prop ) {
    return new Foo(
      arguments.length >= 1 ? arr : this.arr,
      arguments.length >= 2 ? prop : this.isOn
    );
  },

  a: function() {
    var result = [];
    // do something and push to result
    if ( this.prop ) // do something different with result
    return this.clone( result );
  },

  // This is the method that determines if prop = true in the chain
  b: function() {
    result = [];
    // do something and push to result
    // this time 'prop' must be 'true'
    return this.clone( result, true )
  }

};
```

I've used `arguments.length` here to check whether a parameter was passed, you could as well test against `undefined` or use simple `arr || this.arr` for always-truthy properties.

Comment: Worked perfectly! I had to change the context of `newFoo` throughout the code and add quite a few `var self = this` to keep the context right but it seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

change 'a' function to

```
a: function() {
    var result = [];
    // do something and push to result
    if ( this.prop ){} // so something different with result
    return newFoo( result );
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Foo( arr, prop ) {
    this.arr = arr;
    this.isOn = prop || false; // if prop is undefined, set false
}
```

This should sort out your problem.

If you dont add the `prop` argument, `isOn` will be set `undefined`. That's why you get `undefined` as output.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I'm aware of that, plus `undefined` is falsy... What I want is to keep passing `prop` without actually having to pass the old value into every new instance if that's somehow possible/ Maybe a different approach?